# How to generate non-repeating random numbers in a function within a class?

Tags: python

Random numbers in functions stay as it is, e.g. when the number is 1, it stays 1. But when it is taken outside of a function, it generates other numbers.

How to generate non-repeating random numbers in a function?

```
from random import *
randomEnemyNames = ["Gandalf", "Batman", "Magikarp", "Ed Sheeran", "Justin Bieber"]
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.attackPhysical = getrandbits(4)
        self.attackMagical = getrandbits(5)
        self.enemyAttack = getrandbits(6)
        self.critChance = random()
        self.randomHeal = getrandbits(3)
    def attack(self, enemy):
        #inside the class and functions
        print self.critChance #testing with two trials to see if all of it goes random in different ways
        print self.critChance
        print self.attackPhysical
        print self.attackPhysical
        print self.attackMagical
        print self.attackMagical
        print enemy.enemyAttack
        print enemy.enemyAttack
        print self.critChance
        print self.critChance
        print self.randomHeal
        print self.randomHeal
        print self.name
        print enemy.name
the_player = Character("Roy")
the_enemy = Character(choice(randomEnemyNames))
the_player.attack(the_enemy)
#outside the class and functions
print random()
print getrandbits(3)
print getrandbits(4)
print getrandbits(5)
print getrandbits(6)
raw_input("Enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning values to these attributes of your class, not code, it might as well look like this:

```
def getrandbits(n):
    return 9  # I rolled 3d6

class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attackPhysical = getrandbits(4)
    def attack(self, enemy):
        print(self.attackPhysical)
        print(self.attackPhysical)
```

You need to generate a new number each time. Maybe like:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attackPhysical = 4
    def roll(self, n):
        return getrandbits(n)
    def attack(self, enemy):
        physical_dmg = self.roll(self.attackPhysical)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the answer! I have another problem from it but I will try to fix it. Anyways, thank you very much!